# How are you supposed to fire useEffect with more complex dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have encountered the need to be able to add arrays and objects to my useEffect dependency array. What are the recommended approaches for doing this? For arrays I currently use the length of the array which is flawed because an update to the array where its length was constant would not change.

For complex objects too large to recreate with useMemo I am currently using the package useDeepEffect which is doing deep comparisons on the object. I have seen mention of converting it to JSON which is anathema to me. All of my implementations seem slightly hacky here please advise on some recommended way as I have yet encountered any tutorial with state more complex than a counter.

Comment: If you always create a new Array or new Object when updating, instead of mutating the original array or object, you can simply pass the array or object itself as dependancy

Comment: I don't and I only want to run it when the item changes, surely react has a way to do this?

Comment: That you need to handle on situation basis, I would say don't make a new copy if you know you are not going to add or replace anything. But that wouldnt work for all situations

Comment: You can destructure arrays and objects in your component method, and use those values as dependencies in hooks. With optional chaining syntax, you can check for data (ids, names, whatever) within those destructured values. Generally though, dependencies and props should always be new objects/arrays when you expect an update. Refs (mutable objects) cannot be used as dependencies for hooks though, they should be checked explicitly inside your hook function for the value you expect.

Comment: I thought it was bad practice to destructure an array and use its elements as dependencies?

Comment: @nrmad I would agree there. Memoizing the value of the prop, or hoisting the state/data value to be created in a controller (connector) (depending on if that's possible and what should be responsible for it) is definitely preferable when it comes to minimizing re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState({id: 0, content: ""});

useEffect(() => {
 const getItems = async () => {
   const res = await axios.get(apiURL);
   if (res && res.data) {
     setItems(res.data);
   }
}
getItems();
}, [JSON.stringify(items)]);
```

Using deep comparison with lodash:

```
 // For putting object array in dependency array
 function deepCompareEquals(prevVal, currentVal){
     return _.isEqual(prevVal,currentVal ); 
 }
 function useDeepCompareWithRef(value) {
   const ref = useRef();
   if (!deepCompareEquals(value, ref.current)) { 
     ref.current = value; //ref.current contains the previous object value
   }

   return ref.current;
 }

 useEffect(() => {
   const getItems = async () => {
     const res = await axios.get(apiURL + '/items');
     if (res && res.data) {
       setTodos(res.data);
     }
  }
  getItems();

 }, [useDeepCompareWithRef(items)]);
```

For a more thorough discussion, read here: https://betterprogramming.pub/tips-for-using-reacts-useeffect-effectively-dfe6ae951421